# Should I worry about structure alignment in C language when I write applications or it is done automatically?

Tags: c, struct, memory-alignment

I'm trying to understand if structure alignment could affect the programs that I write in C language. It seems that it is something that is handled automatically for us. The question is:

1. Should I worry about it when writing applications ?
2. If yes, then when exactly should I worry about it ?

Comment: Usually not, but it may depend on sveral factirs. What is your platform? What kind of program are you writing? School exercises? Software for embedded systems? Why do you think you need to worry?

Comment: Are you sure `compiler-construction` is the right tag here?

Comment: It can affect matters if you are trying to describe a formal file header, which contains no alignment padding. It isn't unusual here to need a *packed* `struct` (and endianness may apply too).

Comment: In my experience, most of the time you don't need to worry about structure alignment.  You will probably need to think about the sequence of the members of the structure; alternating `char` with `double` would waste a lot of space.  But other than that, the compiler normally deals with it for you.  Serialization and de-serialisation are the main issues you need to think about.  IMO, using a packed attribute is usually a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should care about it since ignoring alignment might produce needlessly memory consuming code.

It's a hard requirement by the standard that struct members are to be allocated so that the first item is at the lowest address. The compiler isn't allowed to re-order them for memory optimization purposes. So if you write a bad struct like this (assuming 32/64 bit CPU):

```
typedef struct
{
  char a;
  /* 3 bytes padding here */
  int  b;
  char c;
  /* 3 bytes padding here */
} bloat_t;

// total size: 12
```

Since the CPU in this example has to read `b` 32 bit aligned, then the compiler has no choice but to insert 3 padding bytes between `a` and `b`. In addition to the 3 padding bytes it has to insert at the end no matter. So when I compile this struct on x86 Linux, I get size 12, which is a waste of space.

This can only be fixed by the programmer, who needs to be aware of such alignment requirements:

```
typedef struct
{
  int  b;
  char a;
  char c;
  /* 2 bytes padding here */
} good_t;

// total size: 8
```

or alternatively

```
typedef struct
{
  char a;
  char c;
  /* 2 bytes padding here */
  int  b;
} good_t;

// total size: 8
```

Answer (score 0):

As other comments/answers have implied, the answer is "it depends."

If you're writing an app for a modern system (meaning ample memory), and your lack of size optimization will only result in the waste of a few K of memory, then no, it probably doesn't matter (though it may not be "best practices").

If, on the other hand, your application may create a huge array of these structures, and/or your struct has enormous inefficiencies, then it might eventually pose a problem.

If your struct is defining a header or a low-level message sequence (commonly found in embedded applications), than it most assuredly will matter, not only because of wasted space, but it can cause operations like memcpy() into the struct not to behave as you might expect. (I realize that such operations also are not "best practices" but they occur all the time in embedded applications, and defensive programming would suggest that you prevent this.) The only remedy for this that I can think of is to define the struct as packed.

Comment: In fact the only truly portable way to use structs is to provide serializing/deserializing functions. Pragmas aren't portable and can also lead to alignment hiccups.